# I am trying to link my android.mk shared library to one of my class and finally calling it from a main activity

Tags: android, android-ndk

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.genralmsg_module, PID: 9240
    java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dlopen failed: cannot locate symbol "__atomic_is_lock_free" referenced by "/data/app/~~W6bxMNwD-C4kynH9qQOk6w==/com.example.genralmsg_module-l1L7p1uDVPEPN0nvzLUVZA==/lib/x86/libcrypto.so"...
        at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:1087)
        at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:1008)
        at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:1664)
        at com.example.genralmsg_module.MainActivity.<clinit>(MainActivity.java:12)
        at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Native Method)
        at android.app.AppComponentFactory.instantiateActivity(AppComponentFactory.java:95)
        at androidx.core.app.CoreComponentFactory.instantiateActivity(CoreComponentFactory.java:45)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1253)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3353)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3601)
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:85)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2066)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7656)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:947)
D/libEGL: loaded /vendor/lib/egl/libEGL_emulation.so
D/libEGL: loaded /vendor/lib/egl/libGLESv1_CM_emulation.so
```

Comment: Most likely, your `libcrypto.so` was built for platform API which is higher than the Android version on your emulator. The rule is that the minSdk for the application should be at least the lowest of all included native libs.

Comment: I think it might be an issue with the C++ runtime library. `__atomic_is_lock_free` might be referring to `std::atomic::is_lock_free`. You might need to use the shared runtime instead of static. See: https://developer.android.com/ndk/guides/cpp-support#shared_runtimes